# Tricky aggregation Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G. 
Here is my data in table ClassGrades:

```
ID      Name    APlusCount  TotalStudents   PctAplus
0       All         44          95          46.31 
1       Grade1A     13          24          54.16
2       Grade1B     11          25          44.00
3       Grade1C     8           23          34.78
4       Grade1D     12          23          52.17
```

The data (APlusCount,TotalStudents) for ID 0 is the sum of data for all classes.

I want to calculate how each class compares to other classes except itself.

Example: 
Take Grade1A that has PctAplus = 54.16.

I want to add all values for Grade1B,Grade1C and Grade1D which is;

```
((Sum of APlusCount for Grade 1B,1C,1D)/(Sum of TotalStudents for Grade 1B,1C,1D))*100

=(31/71)*100=> 43.66%
```

So Grade1A (54.16%) is doing much better when compared to its peers (43.66%)

I want to calculate Peers collective percentage for each Grade.

How do I do this?

Comment: You take that operation and use it on a self cross join,excluding the all row

Comment: If the ID=0, All record a pain point we can remove that from the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to deal with "All" record but for the others this is an approach:

```
select Name, 
   100*(sum(APlusCount) over () - APlusCount) /
   (sum(TotalStudents) over () - TotalStudents) as result
from grades
where name <> 'All';

NAME        RESULT
=================================
Grade1A     43.661971830986
Grade1B     47.142857142857
Grade1C     50
Grade1D     44.444444444444
```

See example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c1ca/7)

Comment: The only criticism I would have of your excellent solution is that the `PARTITION BY` clause is unnecessary. When using an aggregate function as a window function it can be omitted, e.g.: `sum(TotalStudents) over ()` works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be to leverage the `All` record for totals (self cross join as mentioned in the comments), i.e.,

```
WITH g1 AS (
    SELECT apluscount, totalstudents
      FROM grades
     WHERE name = 'All'
)
SELECT g.name, 100*(g1.apluscount - g.apluscount)/(g1.totalstudents - g.totalstudents)
  FROM grades g, g1
 WHERE g.name != 'All';
```

However I think that @Wernfried's solution is better as it doesn't depend on the existence of an `All` record.

**UPDATE**

Alternately, one could use an aggregate along with a `GROUP BY` in the `WITH` statement:

```
WITH g1 AS (
    SELECT SUM(apluscount) AS apluscount, SUM(totalstudents) AS totalstudents
      FROM grades
     WHERE name != 'All'
)
SELECT g.name, 100*(g1.apluscount - g.apluscount)/(g1.totalstudents - g.totalstudents)
  FROM grades g, g1
 WHERE g.name != 'All';
```

Hope this helps. Again, the solution using window functions is probably the best, however.